# Failed to start the Apache service

Tags: apache-httpd

When I'm trying to run the apache it is showing me this error:

```
[manideep@localhost ~]$ sudo  httpd -t
Syntax OK

[manideep@localhost ~]$ sudo service httpd start

Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[manideep@localhost ~]$ sudo service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-03-05 15:52:12 PST; 6s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 4115 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4110 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4110 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain httpd[4110]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain httpd[4110]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address ...0.0:80
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain httpd[4110]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain httpd[4110]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain kill[4115]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 05 15:52:12 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: "Address already in use" is fairly self explanatory :-) You either have something else listening on :80, or `Listen 80` multiple times in config files.

Answer (score 4):

You need to find out what program is occupying port `80`,

```
netstat -ltp | grep :80
```

Then kill that process and restart apache service

Answer (score 1):

Could be problem with website `*.conf` file. This command could give a hint:

```
apachectl configtest
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it.

`sudo service apache2 start`

Job for `apache2.service failed` because the control process exited with error code.
See `systemctl  status apache2.service` and "`journalctl  -xe`" for details.

There was configuration issue in `000-default.conf`. I had not closed the VirtualHost Tag properly.